# Word for what is sold by companies to investors

Tags: word-request, nouns, translation, legalese

What is the word (or phrase) used to refer to what is sold by companies to investors? When an investor comes to own more than 50% of them, he becomes the owner of the company:

In French it is: "Les parts d'une entreprise"

Could it be something like: "The parts of a company"?

Comment: It may be possible to translate what I mean without using that word at all, considering that what is bought by investors is the company itself : "They bought 50% of the company Axa Real Estate."

Comment: Ownership of a majority of the voting rights in a company only provides a "controlling interest" or "control" of a company.  The minority shareholders still have ownership rights, so "control" of a company is **not** the same as being "the owner of the company".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In English, owning a **stake** in a company is called [equity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_equity).

Alternatively, you may use **[stake](http://thefreedictionary.com/stake)** (6a) as I used before.

> The equity of a business is decided by the number of shares one owns.

Or

> I have a 33.3% stake in young but upcoming company.

**EDIT:**

[Shares](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/share.html) is also a very likely candidate. It is only applicable to (private or public) **companies**. A partnership or other business entity won't have shares, and any ownership may need to be described by using one of my previous suggestions. In all likeliehood, **shares** is the word you need in this case, and so, props to @snailboat for jolting me awake on a Sunday afternoon.

Comment: I think they might be looking for *shares*.  Maybe you could talk about that briefly, too?

Comment: Yes, I checked, "shares" is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Companies sell "securities" to investors, including "notes", "bonds", "preferred stock", "convertible bonds", "warrants", and "common stock".

"Common stock" usually comes with "voting rights" proportional to the number of shares owned.  (Some companies have multiple classes of stock; certain classes may have more voting rights per "share" than others.)